# Styles and numbering

Tags: microsoft-word, numbering

I have set up a style called "nicole_number".  There are only a few differences to the default numbering...these are:  indentation is 1cm - hanging is by 1cm.

I created the style by firstly clicking on the numbering button - then making my changes - highlighting the number - applying style renaming it to "nicole_number".

Now my problem is when I need to restart this numbering it defaults back to indentation of 0.63 and hanging 0.63cm.  And it leaves the first set of numbers sitting at indentation 1cm hanging at 1cm.

It's not a major problem but a style is a style - it should work

Any suggestions?

Comment: Word corruption.  Did you start out with a new document with your styles template embedded or are you working from an existing document?  Also, did you paste the text in from another document or did you type it in?